# why my code is not giving the right fibonecci number in nth value

Tags: c++, data-structures

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int fibo(int);
int main()
{
    int num;
    cout << "Enter the nth position you want to find the fibonecci number\t ";
    cin >> num;

    cout << "The " << num << "th fibonecci number is " << fibo(num);
}

int fibo(int n)
{
    int j = 0;
    int arr[25];
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = 0;
    }
    arr[1] = 0;
    arr[2] = 1;

    if (n == 1)
    {
        return arr[1];
    }
    else if (n == 2)
    {
        return arr[2];
    }
    else
    {

        for (j = 3; j <= n; j++)
        {
            arr[j] = arr[j - 1] + arr[j - 2];
            cout << arr[j];
        }
        return arr[j];
    }
}
```

when i am compiling the code its giving garbage value but i dont understand why please if you can try to help , here i am using fibonecci using memorizaion .
here i am taking an array`arr[]` for storing the value as a memory.

Comment: Your `for` loop writes 26 values to `arr`. It writes 0 to `arr[0]` to `arr[25]` inclusively. Arrays in C++ start at index 0 and the last element you can access of an array of `n` elements is `n-1`. The loop condition should be `i < n`.

Comment: Your output is being polluted by `cout << arr[j];`. That output has no formatting or white space, so it looks like just a very long sequence of digits.

Comment: The actual problem here is that when you say `return arr[j];`, `j` is equal to `n + 1`, not `n`.

Comment: Not directly related to why you're getting garbage, but do note that this isn't really memoizing anything. When you return from `fibo`, `arr` is destroyed. The next time you call it, it's created and initialized anew. You'd probably want something like a `static std::vector<int> cache;` or something to genuinely save time on future computations.

Comment: Could you please suggest any place where i can learn more about memorization?

Answer (score 0):

The garbage value that you are getting is because of the following reason:

You initialize elements `a[0]` to `a[n]` with `0`, so elements from `a[n+1]` and afterwards are uninitialized (and hence might contain garbage value).

When you exit the `for` loop, the value of `j` is equal to `n+1` and not `n`. So your function returns the garbage value of `a[n+1]`.

You can easily fix this bug by just `return`ing `arr[--j]` instead of `a[j]` after the `for` loop.

Also, you can now comment off the `cout` inside the `for` loop, otherwise it will further spoil your output.

Comment: `return[n];` seems clearer than `return arr[--j];`. Especially since you're not going to be using `j` any further, so in-place modifications like `--j` are kinda pointless.

Comment: @NathanPierson Yes, that's neater.